# sencha touch app very slow on iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch, ad-hoc-distribution

am trying to test my app on iPhone device , i tested it on android device and it works good , and tested it on the iPhone emulator using Xcode and it's extremely fast and reliable ,

but when i tried it using Ad Hoc on iPhone device it was extremely slow and jerky

also , swipe lists  and buttons clicks are very very slow

am using PhoneGap + Sencha Touch

any ideas , please help ? !

Answer (score 1):

performance does vary enormously between devices, and writing platform/device specific paths to degrade on different devices is quite common.

Assuming that it was a moderatly fair comparrison (ie, not a 1st gen iPhone vs Brand new Android device), I would guess that you are either doing something quite Javascript intensive (where the Android phone might just have the edge) or you have tried to enable nice pretty box-shadows/animations for one-platform but not the other.

Biggest speed increases I have found:

- Disable CSS text/box-shadows. (can't stress this one enough!)
- Disable CSS gradients.
- Don't keep lots of Panels alive in the background, destroy anything that is not visible and rebuild it as you need it.
- Stay away from animations unless your panels are very simple.
- If your button handlers do anything complex, Defer them so that the button doesn't appear to stall